# Dynamic Form creation. How to save the data type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am letting the user create forms for something that is named "site".

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var siteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Site_Name:  String,
    Site_Description: String
},{ strict: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model("site", siteSchema);
```

Currently only two mandatory fields.

Users can use a form and they create new fields, which get saved in MongoDB like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d435a512a17af5b0468c56a"),
    "fieldname" : "Site City",
    "fieldtype" : "String",
    "fieldinputtype" : "Text Box",
    "sitecatname" : "Location",
    "fieldorder" : 20,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I generate a form based on these information from this collection.

Problem is it saves all the data with "String" data type.

How can I force other data types? Like Number or Date?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can define the data type in schema itself.

```
var siteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Site_Name:  {type: String},
    Site_Description: {type: String}        
},{ strict: false });
```

So, If you want to assign any other data(like Number) type then :

```
{type: Number}
```

Comment: Sorry. How do I force the data type on the form? I can't edit the model because the form is created dynamically and I don't know the type of each field in advance.

Comment: Then you can declare the data type as mixed for that fields in the schema as : **{type: Schema.Types.Mixed}** This will save the datatype whatever you will pass to it. This is used for the purpose when you don't know the type of each field in advance.

Comment: Jaspreet - I dont know what fields are coming in, Site_name and Site_Description are the mandatory fields. Others are created by users and the form gets generated dynamically. When a user choses a date field, how do I saved that field as a date field in the database